# CSS - .id:hover a:before items jumping around

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a list a horizontal list of 3 with a:before and a:hover. Upon hovering the element jumps around a little before it settles in it's position. Tried 3 popular browsers. Any ideas for a fix?

```
.twitter a:before{
content: url(.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;}

.twitter:hover a:before {
content: url(.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;}
```

http://nobodyfilm.org - middle section twitter - facebook - trailer buttons. It only happens the first time you load the site if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is propably due to loading the image. It disappears for a moment until the :hover image loaded. If you set the width and height of it, it should not jump around, just disappear for the time being.

Instead, you could put them in a sprite and just set the position to fit the right part of the image.

Comment: If you use a sprite, though, you need to set it as a background image instead.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a fixed width for the `:before` and `:after` seclectors. The problem is that the width is being computed by the browser, and while the images load, they do not have a width.

For example:

```
.twitter a:before {
    content: url(.jpg);
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -.4em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
}

.twitter:hover a:before {
    content: url(.jpg);
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -.4em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it works as far as they won't jump around, but as read from comments below the image dissapears instead, and blinks into existence a second too late. I'll read up on 'sprites' in a sec.

Comment: Indeed, as indicated below set the background image to a sprite, and then move it using `background-position`.